# Is there a platform independent way to use "${ENVVAR}more_text" in vim?

Tags: microsoft-windows, unix, environment-variables

I just discovered that I am able to use `${ENVVAR}more_text` in a vim installation on Unix, but not if installed on Windows.

In Unix, I did in a shell:

```
export ABC=/tmp/
echo foo>${ABC}foo
gvim
```

Then, in the newly opened gvim Window, I tried

```
:e ${ABC}foo
```

which opened `/tmp/foo`, as expected.

In Windows, however, I did (`cmd.exe`):

```
set ABC=c:\temp\
echo foo > %ABC%foo
gvim
```

then, in gvim

```
:e ${ABC}foo
```

which opened a (non existing) file literally named `${ABC}foo` (which is not what I expected).

Is there a way to have vim expand the expression `${ABC}` on Windows as well, or an equipotent alternative?

I realize, that for this *simple* example, I could define the environment variable without trailing slash and add the slash in the `:e` command while not using the braces at all. Yet, I want to achieve something more complex than that so that I fell I sort of need the `${ABC}` construct.

**Edit**

As per *muru*s comment: in Windows, after starting gvim, if I do `echo $ABC`, gvim prints `c:\temp\`.

Comment: If you do `echo $ABC` in Windows Vim, do you get any output?

Comment: Yes, it prints c:\temp\

Comment: Based on a loose interpretation of [`:h $HOME`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%24HOME), `${…}` is only for Unix. What if you do `exe 'e' $ABC . "foo"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use backtick expansion, but that does not seem to be working on Windows. So I think the easiest solution is something like this:
`:exe ":e" $ABC."foobar.txt"`